# matlab plot dollar symbol on axis

Tags: matlab

I'd like the tick-mark labels on an axis to be represented in terms of dollars ($).

I've tried:

```
%set(gca, 'ZTickLabel', sprintf('$%d|', get(gca,'ZTickLabel')));
```

This doesn't work when you rotate the graph (which stretches the graph and adds more tickmarks.

I've also tried converting it to a currency using `cur2str`, but that doesn't work either.

Please help!

Comment: In what sense does it "not work"? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Li-aungYip I can't post a screenshot because it is financial information. I can further describe the problem: The Z-Axis displays:  
    `get(gca,'ZTickLabel')
    -50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0 10`  
Then, after I run the regular expression:  
    `sprintf('$%d|', get(gca,'ZTickLabel'))
    $45|$45|$45|$45|$45|$48|$49|$53|$52|$51|$50|$49|$32|$48|$48|$48|$48|$48|$48|$32|$32|`  
For some reason it converts it to this weird set of numbers, and then on the chart, the axis reads:  
    `$49 $48 $45 $45 $45 $45 $45`

Comment: You can anonymise names, places, and numbers, or just generate completely random data. The important thing is the axes on the graph.

Comment: @Li-aungYip I can't upload an image right now, but it would simply show that before I try that expression, the axis reads  
`-50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0 10`  
After the expression, the axis reads:  
`$49 $48 $45 $45 $45 $45 $45`  
Which is definately not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting undefined behaviour is because `XTickLabel` is a **character** array:

```
>> labels = get(gca,'XTickLabel');
>> class(labels)

ans =

char
```

When you pass this to `sprintf`'s `%d` format specifier, it's expecting a single decimal number - not an array of characters - so it converts the characters to their integer representations and prints those.

To see this, try:

```
>> sprintf('%d','1')

ans =

49
```

What you really want to do is treat the character arrays like character arrays:

```
>> labels = get(gca,'XTickLabel')

labels =

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

>> dollar_signs = repmat('$',size(labels,1),1)

dollar_signs =

$
$
$
$
$
$
$
$

>> new_labels = [dollar_signs labels]

new_labels =

$0
$1
$2
$3
$4
$5
$6
$7

>> set(gca,'XTickLabels',new_labels)
```

This has the effect you desire:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works as long as you're not rotating the 3D graph, thereby changing the scale of the axis. If you do that, then it uses the wrong tick labels to represent the ticks. For example `$10 $0 $-10 $-20 $-30 $-40 $-50` becomes `$-30 $-40 $-50` if you look at the graph from a different angle (which does not correspond correctly to the graph). I guess I'll just not rotate the graph, then.

Comment: You could set the graph tick labels to `ZTickMode=auto`, which resets the axis labels, and then perform the procedure again.