# how to check for extended ascii characters in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

Does anyone know how to detect non ASCII characters in matlab.

i thought of detecting the presence of non ASCII characters through regular expressions

```
if (regexpi('hello world%^&%','![A-Z]*'))display('You have non ascii characters')
```

but it doesn't seem to work

update:-

```
   if (regexpi('hello word','^[A-Za-z0-9]*'))
   display('You have chosen to overwrite!');
   end
```

displays You have chosen to overwrite!

Comment: I suspect that your code was meant to be something like this:  `if (regexpi('hello world%^&%','[^A-Z]*'))display('You have non uppercase letter chacters'); end`.  But that only checks for non-upper-case-letters.  Those are all ascii characters.

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate of [Matlab - how to replace all the special characters in a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882609/matlab-how-to-replace-all-the-special-characters-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters `%^&` *are* ASCII characters, they just aren't *letters*. If you are wanting to test if there are any non-letters, you could do this:

```
if (regexpi('hello world%^&%','[^ A-Z]'))
  display('You have non-letter characters');
end
```

Note that I included a space in the search expression so that spaces are allowed in the string. To allow *any* whitespace character, use `'[^\sA-Z]'` as the search expression.

If you instead want to check for the presence of [extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) characters, you don't even need regular expressions. You can just check if any of the numeric encodings for the characters in your string are greater than or equal to 128, like so:

```
if any('hello world ÁÂÃÄÅ' >= 128)
  display('You have extended ASCII characters');
end
```

Comment: i updated my question. What i really meant was detecting extended ASCII characters.

Comment: This trick works because MATLAB represents strings as arrays of 8-bit integers - so all the tricks you would use on a numerical array also work on strings. This includes things like `repmat()`, `horzcat()` and `vertcat()`, which is [occasionally useful.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093288/matlab-plot-dollar-symbol-on-axis/10094066#10094066)

Answer (score 1):

To check for non-printable ascii (including xtended ascii) codes

```
[^\s\x{20}-\x{7e}]
```

To check for just extended ascii codes

```
[\x{80}-\x{ff}]
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Maybe you need to use Matlab regexp(). Here is a link http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html?nocookie=true. Check character classes.